# How can I import and split lines with ASCII separator?

Tags: files-and-directories

[image]

This is my data file, each line was separated by `SOH`, maybe hex `\x001`,

I've tried some options of `ReadList`, and `Import`.

```
ReadList[file,"Record"]
```

[image]

Well, the problem is not don't know `RecordSeparators`, but what separator character is for `SOH`.

Luckily, I found one method, Copy `SOH` into somewhere [address bar/Text Cell], and then you'll see a empty box.  Show CellExpression of the Text Cell, then you'll see

`"\.01"`  that's the right separator

Comment: See the docs for `ReadList[ ... , RecordSparators->...]`

Comment: @belisarius Hi, first time, I don't know what's the right separator, now I know that's `\.01`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works. Use `BinaryReadList` and remove binary `1` which is code for SOH, then convert back to string

make file

```
>echo -e "2014111\x01ab6f2ed5\x01ce34cbef" > file.txt
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Go to Mathematica and type

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = BinaryReadList["file.txt"]
data = SplitBy[data, (# != 1 && # != 10) &]
data = DeleteCases[data, {1} | {10}]  (*SOH and \n removed*)
r = FromCharacterCode[#] & /@ data
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullForm[r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
ReadList[StringToStream@"2014111\\.01ab6f2ed5\\.01ce34cbef", Record, RecordSeparators -> "\\.01"]

(*{"2014111", "ab6f2ed5", "ce34cbef"}*)
```

Remove one slash after copying to your notebook for testing.